# Cloud Function with too many insertions in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-functions

Good morning,

I'm developing a cloud function that when someone deposits a file in a bucket, the function moves it to another bucket, performs an insert in BigQuery (getting info from another table with info from the file) and deletes the file from the original bucket.

The problem is that usually about 100 files are deposited at once and this causes the function to fail because too many insertions are made in BigQuery and this causes that the insert from that file is not inserted and the file is not deleted from the original bucket.

The function do something like this:

```js
async function archive(data, context) {

const file = data; 

console.log(`Detected new or overwritten file 'gs://${file.bucket}/${file.name}'`); // 'finalize' GCS trigger

 const filepath = file.name.split('/');

 const filename = filepath.slice(-1).join('/');
 const filenameWithoutExtension = filename.split('.').slice(0, -1).join('.')
 const filenameData = filenameWithoutExtension.split('_');

 const fileData = { // exemple : 0023_ROMERO_2021_02.xml
    id_file: filenameData[0],
    name: filenameData[1],
    year: filenameData[3],
    month: filenameData[4]
  };

await copyFile(srcBucketName, srcFilename, destBucketName,...)

const [job] = await bigquery.createQueryJob({
    query: `INSERT INTO table1 (....)
    SELECT
      ...
      timestamp('${file.timeCreated}')
    FROM
      table2
    WHERE
      month = '${file.month}'
      and year = '${file.year}'
      and id_file = '${file.id_file}'
      `,
location: 'EU',
  });

console.log(`BigQuery job ${job.id} started.`);

await job.getQueryResults();
console.log(`BigQuery job ${job.id} completed.`);

await deleteFile(file.bucket, file.name);

console.log('Completed');
}
```

There is a way to solve this problem?

Thanks in advance

Comment: your code seem incomplete. Can you show how you read the file? Do you perform loops? What's your data structure and why are you performing an "INSERT SELECT"? There is a lot of missing pieces!

Comment: in addition to questions above - what is the "maximum instances number" attribute for the deployed cloud function? If the limitation is based on the number of simultaneous BigQuery requests, it may be possible to restrict that threshold.

Comment: I did add more information in the code but I think is not relevant because the problem is the number of the insertions.
I don't need read the file, just get the info from the name of the file, to know how to get the info from the database before the insert.

Comment: @al-dann 5 dml operations per 10 sec https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/quotas

Comment: in my personal experience, using DML in BigQuery is rarely make sense. Do you think loading or streaming may be acceptable in your case (the DDL is to be affected by that change)? At the same time - if you would like to use BigQuery for 'state machine' management - it may be not the best choice...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bigquery has limitations, which we cannot over come it, but you can customize your to handle it.

***Solution Proto type***:-

1. Create a wrapper script/code which will be responsible to list all files landed over GCS- bucket.
2. Create a loop in wrapper code to process each file sequentially or a bath of Small parallel loading instance. These sequentially/small-parallel instance will call your Function for each file.